# iterate over string (UAX #29)

Tags: raku

```
say $s.substr($_, 1) for 0..^$s.chars
```

is the shortest I can find. Can you golf it to a reasonable size and avoid the repetition?

Perl 5 is shorter: `say for split /\b{g}/, $s`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `comb` method without an argument will pick out every character, thus:

```
.say for $s.comb;
```

Will do what is desired (and is shorter than the Perl 5 version too :-)).